# Tank pressure drops as water spigot runs, then pump shuts off

Tags: plumbing, water, water-pressure, well, well-pump

I have a well with a water hose spigot mounted between the well and pressure tank. When I run the hose the pressure drops and the pump comes on correctly. But, the pressure in the tank never builds back up. The pressure continues to drop until there is no pressure in the tank and the pump shuts off. I have to close the water spigot and keep building the pressure back up in the tank, then turn the hose back on and off.

Comment: Sounds like the well pump can't keep up with the hose output. The pressure tank is of no help since it should have a check valve to keep water from backflowing to the well.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @JonCuster

Comment: Is it a problem to have the spigot upstream of the pressure tank?

Comment: Generally, while they have hose threads as a matter of form (and so they can drain somewhere convenient), the valve installed there is intended for draining the system, not for using as a hose supply. It's possible, depending on specifics of your system that it might be drawing from an unsuitable location for a hose to draw from (such as the jet line of a jet pump) or there is the simpler "it's just drawing too much" (in which case turning the hose down, rather than fully off should allow pressure to build.) [Edit] to add some pictures, perhaps.